# Why does this return None? Instead of returning fact?

Tags: python, return

(it returns none)---> why?

```
fact = 1
def factorial(n):
    if (n-1)!=0:
        global fact
        fact=fact*n
        n=n-1
        print(fact)
        factorial(n)
    else:
        return fact
      
n=int(input())
g=factorial(n)
print(g)
```

Comment: Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to format it suitably, tag it with the language you're using, and provide information about what you've done to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Also:  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function returning none in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215141/recursive-function-returning-none-in-python)

Comment: Because in the `if` block, you are _calling_ factorial() but not _returning_ its result.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to return `factorial(n)` in factorial function, otherwise it just gets called and does not return any result in the calling function. Also, you don't need the global variable, simply pass it along with `n` in the `factorial` function itself when doing recursive call.

Also, there's a cleanest solution without any unnecessary variables:

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

And if you dont wanna reinvent the wheel just use `math` module:

```py
import math

math.factorial(1234)
```