# python why does function never reach return statement?

Tags: python, function

I always get the output `None` instead of `False`

My code:

```
def bi_search(elements: list, x) -> bool:
    i = len(elements)/2-1
    i = int(i)
    print(i)
    if i == 0:
        return False
    elif x == elements[i]:
        return True
    elif x < elements[i]:
        e = elements[0:i + 1]
        bi_search(e, x)
    elif x > elements[i]:
        e = elements[i+1:len(elements)]
        bi_search(e, x)
```

commands:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 20, 30, 41, 100]
print(bi_search(my_list, 21))
```

Output:

```
4
1
0
None
```

I don't get it, it even says that is i = 0 right before the statement, so why do I not get False as a result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function returning none in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215141/recursive-function-returning-none-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you fall into 3rd or 4th case and the `bi_search()` recursively calls itself you forgot to take into account that the call  will eventually return and the flow will continue from there further. And because you miss `return` for these cases, Python jumps out of the `elif` and reaches ends of the function. As there's no more code in the function to execute, Python exits that function and returns execution to caller, but as caller expected to get something back (the return value) from the function it called we got a problem. Python solves this problem it goes with use of `None` to still return something it does not have really and also to indicate that it had nothing better to give back.

Your code should look this way:

```py
def bi_search(elements: list, x) -> bool:
    i = len(elements)/2-1
    i = int(i)
    print(i)
    if i == 0:
        return False
    elif x == elements[i]:
        return True
    elif x < elements[i]:
        e = elements[0:i + 1]
        return bi_search(e, x)
    elif x > elements[i]:
        e = elements[i+1:len(elements)]
        return bi_search(e, x)
```

and then the output is as expected:

```bash
4
1
0
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have return statements in the last 2 `elif`, you want to return the value of recursive call

```
def bi_search(elements: list, x) -> bool:
    i = len(elements)/2-1
    i = int(i)
    print(i)
    if i == 0:
        return False
    elif x == elements[i]:
       return True
    elif x < elements[i]:
      e = elements[0:i + 1]
      return bi_search(e, x)
    elif x > elements[i]:
       e = elements[i+1:len(elements)]
       return bi_search(e, x)
```